# Shortest way to write this (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Is there any chainable method / way to write this in one line

```
var $d = $('<div>').addClass('clear');
$('.clearAfter').after($d);
```

The following will add css style to clearAfter rather

`$('.clearAfter').after('<div>').addClass('clear');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use insertAfter:

```
$('<div>').addClass('clear').insertAfter('.clearAfter');
```

Or you can simply do:

```
$('.clearAfter').after('<div class="clear" />');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), which I find the most readable:

```
$('<div />').addClass('clear').insertAfter('.clearAfter');
```

Or, less pretty:

```
$('.clearAfter').after($('<div>').addClass('clear'));
```

Comment: you don't need the angled brackets in the selector, just `$('div')`

Comment: @mdma - this isn't a selector, it creates the element: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: +1 thanks - not sure how I missed that, but I've obviously only used the selector notation!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
$('.clearAfter').after($('<div>').addClass('clear'));
```